# A is to B is what C is to D or A is to B as C is to D?

Tags: grammaticality

I've seen both 'what' and 'as' interchangeably used in many sentences the latter being more common. I want to know which usage is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, the second one is correct.
A is to B **as** C is to D.

But the same can be conveyed by using 'what'. This is how: A is to B **is what** C is to D. With the missing **is** before 'what', the sentence is incorrect.

The completeness of the sentence is the key to understand such differences. I hope this helps.